# Firefox no longer works through ssh -D tunnel

Tags: firefox, proxy, ssh-tunnel

Quite a while ago I started using an ssh tunnel so I could access services back in the Uk that require a UK client address (such as my library and my doctor).

So I have been using "ssh -fTnN -D 1080 chris@isbd.uk" and setting up the proxy configuration in Firefox to use host 127.0.0.1 and port 1080.

However this didn't work when I was in France last week, I'm not sure when it stopped working (maybe in the last year or so), it now give an error:-

```
Secure Connection Failed

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Has anyone any idea how to fix this?  The proxy works for things like curl and lynx so it would seem to be a Firefox issue brought about by security paranoia.

Answer (score 0):

Found this because I had the same problem today - same error message, no useful information - on fedora-34 using Firefox 94.0 and OpenSSH_8.6p1. Also tried GNU Icecat 78.15.0esr same result. Can't test `cromium-browser` because the system proxy settings need Network Manager, `curl` with `--preproxy sockst5://127.0.0.2:3128` works fine.

Thought my server config was broken but it also applied to all other connections while the browser was set to use the proxy and the system I was worked from other setups where one ff version is in between the two I tested on fedora-33 and the other being version 94.0.1-1 on arch.

that's as far as I'm willing to invest time to debug this for now